# R/ Shiny Select DataFrom Column in Data Table

Tags: r, shiny, datatable, output, project

Say for instance my data is:

```
Year Car      Doors Cylinder Transmission
2003 Nissan   4     4        MT
2006 Nissan   4     4        MT
2003 Honda    2     6        AT
```

I want Shiny to return the first instance MT shows. How would I go about that?

My code:

```
df_example <- cars %>%
    filter(cylinder = 4, 
           doors = 4) %>%
    slice(1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can modify the code without `filter`

```
library(dplyr)
cars %>%
       slice(which(Cylinder == 4 & Doors == 4)[1])
```

-output

```
#    Year    Car Doors Cylinder Transmission
#1 2003 Nissan     4        4           MT
```

If we need to extract the 'Transmission', use `pull`

```
cars %>%
       slice(which(Cylinder == 4 & Doors == 4)[1]) %>%
       pull(Transmission)
```

---

NOTE: In the `filter`, the expression used is assignment operator (`=`) instead of  comparison operator (`==`).  Also, `R` is case-sensitive i.e. it would need the exact column name and not the lower-case column name.  Based on the data showed, the column names are `Cylinder` and `Doors` and not `cylinder` and `doors`

#### data

```
cars <- structure(list(Year = c(2003L, 2006L, 2003L), Car = c("Nissan", 
"Nissan", "Honda"), Doors = c(4L, 4L, 2L), Cylinder = c(4L, 4L, 
6L), Transmission = c("MT", "MT", "AT")), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Comment: So I got the same output, but how do I get it to display just MT?

Comment: @lmnguyen you can use `pull`  updated the post

Comment: That did it! Thank you so much!